# Как и когда слово "специально" обрело значение "нарочно, намеренно"?

Tags: этимология, семантика, лексикология

Очевидно, оно пришло из латинского, а вот почему и когда обрело такое значение в русском?

Comment: Оно всегда имело именно такой смысл, а какое у него должно быть "значение"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наречие «специально» образовалось в русском языке и должно было примкнуть к одному из существующих (в этом языке) разрядов (групп) наречий по  семантике. Для наречия «специально» наиболее близкой оказалась группа наречий цели, к которой относится и наречие «нарочно».
https://studfile.net/preview/5873433/page:21/
Думается, что это обстоятельство и стало причиной "объединения" (со временем) значений «специально» и «нарочно».
Наиболее раннее из вхождений в НК наречия «специально» со значением «нарочно» относится к первой половине 20 –го века.
Поймет Старик, что про плесень он написал так, специально, чтобы «поддать жару», а на самом деле, конечно же, и мысли нет, что опять может заплесневеть Россия. [С. Д. Мстиславский. Грач ― птица весенняя (1937)]
Со временем «специально» приобрело почти все значения слова «нарочно»: сознательно, с определенной целью, на заказ, умышленно, (пред)намеренно, вопреки / назло.
Включила, и загорелась только одна лампочка ― прямо над Юрой! Как специально! Ну, мы и смеялись! [З. С. Лелянова. Дневник (1963)]
Верно, это сделано так специально, чтоб сравнивать. [Анатолий Кузнецов. Артист миманса (1968)]
― А насчет драки ― это же не специально, а так получилось. [Г. А. Галахова. Легкий кораблик ― капустный листок (1975)]
Да разве на него можно обижаться, не специально ведь, с детства у него эта дурацкая привычка. [В. В. Голявкин. Уверенность (1973)]
[Он (муж)] Ну, не нарочно, разумеется… Не специально, так сказать. Я тоже в какой-то мере… был заинтересованное лицо… [Л. Н. Разумовская. Счастье (1981)]
Область пересечения значений слов «нарочно» и «специально» фиксируется в толковом словаре Т. Ф. Ефремовой (2000г):

- НАРОЧНО нареч. 1) Имея цель, намеренно. 2) разг. Вопреки кому-л., чему-л., назло. 3) разг. В шутку, не всерьез.
- СПЕЦИАЛЬНО нареч. 1) Только, исключительно. 2) Намеренно, с определенной целью.

Answer (score 1):

**Не вполне ясная** по времени (как и когда) тема...  **Коротко можно сказать так**: сначала оба слова получили **целевое** значение,  потом ***нарочно*** стало обозначать умышленную цель в разговором стиле, а уже позже ***специально*** позаимствовало это значение.

Здесь надо **сравнивать** наречия "специально" и "нарочно", причем в определенном **плане**. Оба слова в русском языке имеют **направленное** значение цели. В этом их сходство.

Но ***специально*** ― это скорее нейтральная/книжная лексика, а вот ***нарочно*** ― разговорный стиль. И значения у слова тоже "разговорные",  с дополнительной коннотацией: не просто с целью, а иногда с какой-то сомнительной целью (назло, в шутку). Вот этот момент интересно зафиксировать.

Интересна **история** и самого наречия "***нарочно***", об этом можно прочитать в этимологических словарях. Его исходное нейтральное значение ― намеренно, с определенной целью,  но есть и другие (уже названные) значения.

Можно сравнить:

***Нарочитый*** буквально — «известный, именитый» в отличие от сегодняшнего значения — «показной, умышленный».

**НАРОЧИ́ТО**. Нареч. к нарочитый. Иногда я грубил ***нарочито***, из протеста против чего-то чуждого мне и раздражавшего меня. М. Горький, Мои университеты.  [Другие примеры](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE)

[Происхождение слова нарочно](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)

[Происхождение слова нарочитый](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Это прекрасный ответ, но только не на поставленные вопросы «почему? и когда?» слово "специально" обрело значение "нарочно".

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую чуть позже даты добавить...